# Using ejabberd for time restricted chats

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

We are developing a chat application that should have time restriction.

For example, a user can search for other users and add them. The user should be notified that someone else added him.
When the user accepts chat can begin between the two users but the chat should only be limited for 1 minute.

Is it possible to achieve the above with ejabberd?

Answer (score 0):

- Most existing XMPP servers (such as `ejabberd`, `openfire`, etc) support the functionalities you want, but except chat timeout after 1min.
- Although XMPP does not have the concept of `timeout`, you can easily implement this function on your client side. E.g., let both users join a MUC (multi-user chat) and have a timer to record the start time of a chat. Then destroy the MUC after 1 minute.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion. One thing im worried about with this approach is that the user uses another client like adium and connect to the xmpp server thus bypassing the whole thing. What do you think?